# Why is methyl chloride a primary alkyl halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, molecular-structure

> In a primary (1°) halogenoalkane, the carbon which carries the halogen atom is only attached to one other alkyl group.
>   [Chemguide.co.uk](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/haloalkanes/background.html)

For $\ce{CH3Cl}$, the carbon which carries the halogen atom has no other alkyl groups attached, yet my class notes say "the alkyl halide has a primary centre". So is a primary alkyl group one with is attached to **0** or **1** other alkyl group and not just **1**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

The IUPAC defines [alkyl groups](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00228.html) in the following manner:

> Univalent groups derived from alkanes by removal of a hydrogen atom from any carbon atom $\ce{–C_{$n$}H_{$2n+1$}}$. The groups derived by removal of a hydrogen atom from a terminal carbon atom of unbranched alkanes form a subclass of normal alkyl (*n*-alkyl) groups $\ce{H(CH2)_{$n$}}$. The groups $\ce{RCH2}$, $\ce{R2CH~(R \neq H)}$, and $\ce{R3C~(R \neq H)}$ are primary, secondary and tertiary alkyl groups, respectively.

Note that for primary alkyl groups hydrogen may be a remainder, i.e. $\ce{R $=$ H, Alkyl, Aryl}$, therefore any halogenoalkane with the structure $\ce{RH2C-X}$ is primary.